# golang: index efficiency of array

Tags: go

It's a simple program.
test environment: debian 8, go 1.4.2

union.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    t int32
    u int64
}

func test() (total int64) {
    a := [...]A{{1, 100}, {2, 3}}

    for i := 0; i < 5000000000; i++ {
        p := &a[i%2]
        total += p.u
    }
    return
}
func main() {
    total := test()
    fmt.Println(total)
}
```

union.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    int t;
    long u;
};

long test()
{
    struct A a[2];
    a[0].t = 1;
    a[0].u = 100;
    a[1].t = 2;
    a[1].u = 3;

    long total = 0;
    long i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++) {
        struct A* p = &a[i % 2];
        total += p->u;
    }
    return total;
}
int main()
{
    long total = test();
    printf("%ld\n", total);
}
```

result compare:

go:

```
257500000000

real    0m9.167s
user    0m9.196s
sys 0m0.012s
```

C:

```
257500000000

real    0m3.585s
user    0m3.560s
sys 0m0.008s
```

It seems that the go compiles lot of weird assembly codes (you could use objdump -D to check it).

For example, why `movabs $0x12a05f200,%rbp` appears twice?

```
  400c60:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400c62:       48 bd 00 f2 05 2a 01    movabs $0x12a05f200,%rbp
  400c69:       00 00 00 
  400c6c:       48 39 e8                cmp    %rbp,%rax
  400c6f:       7d 46                   jge    400cb7 <main.test+0xb7>
  400c71:       48 89 c1                mov    %rax,%rcx
  400c74:       48 c1 f9 3f             sar    $0x3f,%rcx
  400c78:       48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
  400c7b:       48 29 cb                sub    %rcx,%rbx
  400c7e:       48 83 e3 01             and    $0x1,%rbx
  400c82:       48 01 cb                add    %rcx,%rbx
  400c85:       48 8d 2c 24             lea    (%rsp),%rbp
  400c89:       48 83 fb 02             cmp    $0x2,%rbx
  400c8d:       73 2d                   jae    400cbc <main.test+0xbc>
  400c8f:       48 6b db 10             imul   $0x10,%rbx,%rbx
  400c93:       48 01 dd                add    %rbx,%rbp
  400c96:       48 8b 5d 08             mov    0x8(%rbp),%rbx
  400c9a:       48 01 f3                add    %rsi,%rbx
  400c9d:       48 89 de                mov    %rbx,%rsi
  400ca0:       48 89 5c 24 28          mov    %rbx,0x28(%rsp)
  400ca5:       48 ff c0                inc    %rax
  400ca8:       48 bd 00 f2 05 2a 01    movabs $0x12a05f200,%rbp
  400caf:       00 00 00 
  400cb2:       48 39 e8                cmp    %rbp,%rax
  400cb5:       7c ba                   jl     400c71 <main.test+0x71>
  400cb7:       48 83 c4 20             add    $0x20,%rsp
  400cbb:       c3                      retq   
  400cbc:       e8 6f e0 00 00          callq  40ed30 <runtime.panicindex>
  400cc1:       0f 0b                   ud2    
        ...
```

while the C assembly is more clean:

```
0000000000400570 <test>:
  400570:       48 c7 44 24 e0 64 00    movq   $0x64,-0x20(%rsp)
  400577:       00 00 
  400579:       48 c7 44 24 f0 03 00    movq   $0x3,-0x10(%rsp)
  400580:       00 00 
  400582:       b9 64 00 00 00          mov    $0x64,%ecx
  400587:       31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
  400589:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40058b:       48 be 00 f2 05 2a 01    movabs $0x12a05f200,%rsi
  400592:       00 00 00 
  400595:       eb 18                   jmp    4005af <test+0x3f>
  400597:       66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40059e:       00 00 
  4005a0:       48 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%rcx
  4005a3:       83 e1 01                and    $0x1,%ecx
  4005a6:       48 c1 e1 04             shl    $0x4,%rcx
  4005aa:       48 8b 4c 0c e0          mov    -0x20(%rsp,%rcx,1),%rcx
  4005af:       48 83 c2 01             add    $0x1,%rdx
  4005b3:       48 01 c8                add    %rcx,%rax
  4005b6:       48 39 f2                cmp    %rsi,%rdx
  4005b9:       75 e5                   jne    4005a0 <test+0x30>
  4005bb:       f3 c3                   repz retq 
  4005bd:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
```

Could somebody explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you build the go app with array bounds checks disabled using `-gcflag -B` option and re-run your benchmark?

Comment: @kostya, I try the flag, but it does not help.

Comment: @kingluo Running your code with `gccgo` and -O3 yields similar results to C: `time go run -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags -O3 foo.go` Output: `real 0m3.667s user 0m3.644s`. So it's probably some optimization gcc is doing.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, yes, the gccgo is better in this case. Does gccgo support go 1.3 or higher?

Comment: @kingluo gccgo 4.9 is the latest release and it's compliant with go 1.2, the next release should be compliant with 1.4. But IIRC there weren't many changes in the language spec since then. I'm not sure if you can use 1.4 std packages with gccgo though.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is the the array bounds checking.  In the disassembly dump for the Go program, there is:

```
400c89:       48 83 fb 02             cmp    $0x2,%rbx
400c8d:       73 2d                   jae    400cbc <main.test+0xbc>
...
400cbc:       e8 6f e0 00 00          callq  40ed30 <runtime.panicindex>
400cc1:       0f 0b                   ud2
```

So if `%rbx` is greater than or equal to 2, then it jumps down to a call to `runtime.panicindex`.  Given you're working with an array of size 2, that is clearly the bounds check.  You could make the argument that the compiler should be smart enough to skip the bounds check in this particular case where the range of the index can be determined statically, but it seems that it isn't smart enough to do so yet.

While you're seeing a noticeable performance difference for this micro-benchmark, it might be worth considering whether this is actually representative of your actual code.  If you're doing other stuff in your loop, the difference is likely to be less noticeable.

And while bounds checking does have a cost, in many cases it is better than the alternative of the program continuing with undefined behaviour.

Comment: As suggested by @kostya, I try -gcflag -B, but it's just 1 second quicker than original one, and is still far from C. So there is other reasons?

Comment: @kingluo Your creating a local stack variable to a pointer to the array is redundant. You'll get a couple of seconds speedup by making the whole array an array of pointers.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: are you sure about that? It looks like the only memory load after the bounds check (at `400c96`) is loading the value of `p.u`.  If you had an array of pointers to structs, it'd need to do two loads.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge I haven't looked at the generated asm, but it just works a bit faster (shaved ~1.5 seconds off on my machine). maybe it triggers some other optimization.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge another thing that shaved 2 seconds off was doing `i & 1` instead of `i % 2`. So after these 2 optimizations I'm getting 6.3 seconds. But as I wrote in a comment to the question, running via gccgo makes it run just as fast as C.

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't do the `i % 2` => `i & 1` transformation because they are only equivalent for non-negative integers.  If we make i a `uint`, then the compiler does the transformation automatically.  But still, it isn't clear what value there is in optimising this micro-benchmark to death.